# How do I retrieve a document along with just one of it children?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document similar to the following

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e7b6cb9606503483494c63a"},"ProductId":{"$binary":{"base64":"V9+9bOaj8kyWrPwdAm0rBQ==","subType":"03"}},"ProductName":"TestProduct1","ProductItems":[{"_t":"ProductItem","ProductId":{"$binary":{"base64":"V9+9bOaj8kyWrPwdAm0rBQ==","subType":"03"}},"Code":"TP1A"},
{"_t":"ProductItem","ProductId":{"$binary":{"base64":"V9+9bOaj8kyWrPwdAm0rDE==","subType":"03"}},"Code":"TP1B"}]}
```

What I would like to do is return by a query on ProductItem.Code that returns a product with the single matching child productItem. So preserving the object structure but eliminating all but the single matching child.

Is this possible or do I need to do two queries and then combine the objects on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to run two queries. MongoDB allows document transformation with projection.

## Find + Projection with `$elemMatch` operator. (include / exclude)

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  productId: 1,
  productName: 1,
  ProductItems: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "Code": "TP1A"
    }
  }
})
```

## Aggregation with `$filter` operator (advanced features)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      ProductItems: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$ProductItems",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.Code",
              "TP1A"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```